# OpenPGP (RFC4880) - do you agree with my SimpleS2K (string-to-key) implementation?

Tags: pgp, gnupg

Background: I'm writing a GPL Python OpenPGP to JSON parser which I'm testing on files generated with GPG 1.4.16.

If given a passphrase, the parser will generate keys using the string-to-key methods and ultimately decrypt messages.

I'm starting off with symmetric encryption messages:

```
echo "hello" | gpg --s2k-mode=0 --symmetric > symmetric.simples2k.gpg
```

... and using "foo" as the passphrase.

This generates a packet with a `SymmetricKeyEncryptedSessionKeyPacket` and a `SymmetricEncryptedandIntegrityProtectedDataPacket` packet, as expected.

The S2K paramters that GPG created are: Simple S2K (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4880#section-3.7.1.1) with SHA1 hash and AES256 symmetric cipher.

**Problem:** When I derive the key from the passphrase `foo` using SimpleS2K then attempt to decrypt with AES256, it doesn't decrypt correctly. So part 1 of my investigation is verifying that I'm doing the S2K correctly.

Here's my understanding of how to generate the key from the passphrase `foo` using SimpleS2K

1. Create two SHA1 hashers (because AES256 needs 32-byte key, SHA1 produces 20-byte hash)
2. Don't preload hashers[0]
3. Update `hashers[1]` with 0x00
4. Update `hashers[0]` with UTF-8 encoded `foo`
5. Update `hashers[0]` with UTF-8 encoded `foo`
6. Concatenate `hashers[0].digest` plus `hashers[1].digest`
7. Take first 32 bytes of result (ie drop last 8 bytes)

Here's a demonstration implementation in Python 3:

```
import hashlib
from Crypto.Cipher import AES  # using pycrypto==2.6.1


def format_octets(octets):
    return ' '.join(['{:02x}'.format(x) for x in octets])

hasher_0 = hashlib.sha1()
hasher_1 = hashlib.sha1()

hasher_1.update(bytes([0x0]))

hasher_0.update('foo'.encode('utf-8'))
hasher_1.update('foo'.encode('utf-8'))

key = (hasher_0.digest() + hasher_1.digest())[0:32]
print('s2k key: {}'.format(format_octets(key)))

encrypted_data = bytes([
    0x0b, 0x1e, 0xcf, 0x86, 0x33, 0x08, 0xfd, 0x66, 0x9a, 0xf0, 0xbe, 0x48,
    0x62, 0xa4, 0xa5, 0x42, 0x4f, 0xd8, 0x20, 0xfe, 0x16, 0xe4, 0x4c, 0xdb,
    0x80, 0x89, 0xee, 0x34, 0x72, 0xef, 0x52, 0x36, 0x70, 0x15, 0x01, 0x82,
    0xd5, 0x0e, 0xeb, 0x61, 0xba, 0xe7, 0x71, 0x4a, 0x8c, 0x22, 0x6a, 0x9c,
    0x79, 0x8f, 0xe3, 0xda, 0x31, 0xfc, 0xad, 0x14, 0xeb, 0x8a])

block_size = 16  # AES
iv = bytes([0x0] * block_size)  # all-zero initialisation vector

obj = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CFB, iv)
decrypted = obj.decrypt(encrypted_data)

random_octets = decrypted[0: block_size]
repeated_octets = decrypted[block_size: block_size + 2]
plaintext_packets = decrypted[block_size + 2:-20]
sha1 = decrypted[-20:]

print('random octets: {}'.format(format_octets(random_octets)))
print('repeated octets: {}'.format(format_octets(repeated_octets)))
print('plaintext_packets: {}'.format(format_octets(plaintext_packets)))
print('sha1: {}'.format(format_octets(sha1)))
```

Which outputs

```
s2k key: 0b ee c7 b5 ea 3f 0f db c9 5d 0d d4 7f 3c 5b c2 75 da 8a 33 5a 8c aa 40 39 fd bc 02 c0 1a 64 9c
random octets: 48 9b 65 84 01 f7 33 23 0a 6e e4 32 9d c4 ef 99
repeated octets: 56 a8
plaintext_packets: b9 fd 5a 05 6e d2 83 22 22 fe e5 d7 77 dd 93 49 4f 03 fe 13
sha1: ce 7d 93 34 59 f6 71 70 c3 bd 06 94 ad 97 f3 0a 59 72 1d 93
```

The full JSON output is here: https://gist.github.com/paulfurley/5285a6ebce4a30dca12b#file-bad_simples2k-json

Hopefully we can rule out the S2K part and get onto the AES part :)

Thanks!

Comment: Was the null character included in one, but not the other?

Comment: Good question - hopefully it wouldn't be included in either but worth a check

Comment: Also, I believe that GPG compresses data by default.  You might want to see if you have a compressed packet type as your result.  Also make sure that you're using CFB mode with an IV of all zeroes specified.  I'm basing this off section 5.13

Comment: @raz Thanks - however unfortunately I can tell that I'm not decrypting successfully because bytes 15,16 should be equal to 17,18 and they aren't :(

Comment: If you're feeling brave I found the sGPG source line where the magic happens: https://github.com/paulfurley/gnupg-mirror/blob/7a852fba6c3fce4ec6db8ab5287e646249251070/g10/passphrase.c#L1074 It doesn't *look* like it writes the NULL byte but the code's hardly clear :(

Comment: Yeah strlen doesn't count the null byte.  Your code looks fine to me.  Maybe post your code for performing the decryption and what it outputs?

Comment: AES code now included.